# I deleted Google Settings App

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, google-settings

I deleted the Google Settings App on my Xperia and now I can't use Play Store anymore. The reason I did this in the first place is that I was trying to update my whatsapp but insufficient storage error kept occurring so I thought I would delete those applications I don't use. Now that I know I shouldn't have deleted this one in particular, how can I get things back to the they they were?

Thanks

Comment: Flash the Gapps. Now i dont know what you device is so i can help with the tutorials and links so. Please put the device so that i can help you further.

Comment: Restore the backup you certainly made before? (rhetorical hint/reminder to create one next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Google app is supposed to be built into `system/app` I wonder how you managed to uninstall it, unless you have root access. 
 Anyways! What you can do is Download the stock firmware image for your device from the vendor's site and flash it in your device! All the things will be reverted back to default and normal !!

I don't know which Xperia you're using with Android ICS so I won't be able to provide you with links and tuts. Good Luck!!